# How to display next node from XML document on button event

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, button

I am working through w3schools and am stuck on a bit of XML. The following page shows a parsed XML file which has a single node (with several children) displayed as HTML. I always challenge myself to push the code before me to encourage more meaningful learning, but this time I am stuck! Here is the link to the page:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_app_first

The XML file is a mock 'CD catalogue' that contains a list of CD nodes, containing child nodes of artist, title, etc. The page displays a single CD node, selected by the lines:

```
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");  
i=0;
```

What I am trying to do is create a button which, when pressed, increases the value of "i" by 1. Essentially a 'next' button. I have tried to create a button/function combo while treating "i" as a variable. That fails, so I get the feeling that I don't actually understand how XML/DOM works...

I understand that this may be a trivial question but I have tried different search terms on Google and Stack Overflow but with no success. If there's a way to do what I'm trying to, please let me know!

Edit: Eek! I'm so stupid and was so engrossed in this little self-challenge that I didn't even read on to the next section of the page on w3schools, titled "Navigate Between the CDs":

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_applications.asp

I will leave this question as is for people who Google for this, but if you look at w3school's example (click "Try it yourself", is it the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: It might be a good idea to note here that W3Schools isn't a [very good place to start learning JavaScript](http://w3fools.com/). Placing large amount of code into inline event handlers are also frowned upon in real world situations.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="i++;displayCD();">Next</button>
```

EDIT: Take care of moving beyond the length and prev button

```
<button onclick="i++; if (i >= x.length) i = x.length - 1; displayCD()">Next</button>
<button onclick="i--; if (i < 0) i = 0; displayCD()">Prev</button>
```

Comment: Wow. You answered both my questions with magical grace.

I love you :P I tried that line before but only once without the function call and once without the increment. I wouldn't have thought of having both.

Comment: If anyone has enough reputation, please vote up this answer :)

Comment: Oh it was part of the edit- whether there was a more efficient way to do it than on the w3schools example. Thanks for your edit too. That's pretty much what I was after- the barebones code necessary to work.